# np.sort(X,axis=1) doesn't sort array?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, regression

```
# Data
order=3
df = pd.read_csv('singleXregression.csv')
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values
y = y.reshape(len(y),1)
```

This is standard opening for my regression but when I try to sort X with the line:

```
 X = np.sort(X,axis=1)
```

it just doesn't do anything. No error message - just X is still not sorted. I know I can sort it id dataframe but I'm trying to make a template for fast copy-paste and therefore trying to work on indexes instead. Why does this line not work? I understand that X is a 2D numpy array as X.shape is (201,1)

The whole reason why I'm trying to sort it, it's because I'm doing polynomial regression and everything works except for the graph, which is all over the place.  If anyone could help me sorting X or the graph that would be great.

Comment: Beware, in Python `axis=1` is the second axis. You probably want `X = np.sort(X,axis=0)`. But no data to make sure hence a comment and not an answer...

Comment: sorry for confusion X is a data frame of features (that's the reason is called X) but since its a column that's why axis=1. Is there a way of sorting data frame by a column, where column is given by index, not by name? as that would fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
feature=df.columns[0]
df = df.sort_values(by=[feature])
```

This is what did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try

X = X.sort(axis=1)